# Documentation of 'Property of class preceded by question mark'

Tags: c#, properties, nullable, value-type

I have class that uses a `ulong ParentId { get; set; }`and I needed it to be nullable.
Because if the entity (of this class) is added to the database, and has no parent, it must be `null` and not `0`. So I remembered vaguely something about preceding it with a question mark. And it works. See the code below.

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public ulong ?ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:**
Does anyone know where to find the documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) and [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Marked as answer because more documentation provided.

Answer (score 1):

For value type which can be nullable - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx Question mark after a value type is same as `Nullable<T>`